# PHP Update Query Date is not inserted?

Tags: php, mysql

Hello Friends this is my update query.

```
UPDATE bizz_investor_form set    
  Published_Published='publishedyes',
  Published_Listed_and_Discoverable='listedanddiscoverableno',
  Published_Describe_Start_Date='21-10-2013',
  Describe_end_Date='30-10-2013' 
WHERE user_id =136
```

When i run that query the date put in database like 0000-00-00 please help any one.

Comment: What field type is your date field in your database? `DATE`? Try changing the format to `YYYY-MM-DD`

Comment: @FDL  i select DATETIME.

Comment: Maybe it's month-day-year or year-month-day, check the order

Comment: In mysql date type datatype fields take value as '2013-10-30' (yyyy-mm-dd)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change date to like.

```
$startdate = date("Y-m-d",strtotime('21-10-2013'));
$enddate = date("Y-m-d",strtotime('21-10-2013'));
```

then after write your query like.

```
"UPDATE bizz_investor_form set    
  Published_Published='publishedyes',
  Published_Listed_and_Discoverable='listedanddiscoverableno',
  Published_Describe_Start_Date='".$startdate."',
  Describe_end_Date='".$enddate."' 
WHERE user_id =136"
```

Answer (score 2):

Datetime format in mysql is YYYY-MM-DD H:i:s (2013-10-30 11:08:55)

Answer (score 0):

Set field type to `DATE` or change value to `2013-10-30 00:00:00` (mysql dates format yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss)

Answer (score 0):

MySQL's [default DATE field](http://wiki.navicat.com/wiki/index.php/What_is_MySQL%27s_default_DATE/DATETIME_format?) format **is YYYY-MM-DD**.

You can use **[`DATE_FORMAT`](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_date_format.asp)**

```
DATE_FORMAT('1997-10-04 00:00:00', '%W %M %Y');
```